# How to use two column values of a dataframe to select a value from another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate

I hope you are doing well.

This is the dataset I'm using

[image: Data set]

I want to calculate the change of the `BMI` of the users of the App. I got the Id's, the first date of record and the last with the following code

```
BMI_results <- weight_log %>% 
    group_by(Id) %>% 
    summarize(date_min = min(Date), date_max = max(Date)) 

BMI_results
```

The next part is to use that data to get the corresponding BMI of that dates and then substract those numbers. This is the part where I'm stuck. Please help.

```
# The following code is wrong, just for illustration:

BMI_results <- weight_log %>% 
    group_by(Id) %>% 
    summarize(date_min = min(Date), date_max = max(Date)) %>%
    mutate(
            first_BMI = filter(weight_log$BMI, 
                               Id == Id & date_min == Date), 
            last_BMI = filter(weight_log$BMI, 
                              Id == Id & date_max == Date),
            difference = first_BMI-last_BMI 
          )
```

I was expecting to get the values of each BMI, the first and last recorded, and then substract them.

Comment: Please provdie a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/10068985), instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). Share a reproducible format like `dout()` so we can copy/paste into R for testing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
BMI_results <- weight_log %>% 
    group_by(Id) %>% 
    arrange(Date) %>%
    summarize(diff=first(BMI)-last(BMI))
```